# Fill date input with Typescript + Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, date, input

I've been trying to fill a date input with TypeScript with no luck:

I got 3 dates with the following format: dd/MM/yyyy...
So, I've parsed each number to change its format to yyyy-MM-dd then assigned it to the ngModel var of each input using datepipe. I've tried different formats but it doesn't seem to work.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <input type="date" ngModel="inputDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'"">
</div>

<div>
    <input type="date" ngModel="inputDateFrom | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'"">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="date" ngModel="inputDateTo | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'"">
</div>
```

**TS:**

```
let dateFill = data[4] + '/' + data[5] + '/' + data[6];
let parsedDate = dateFill.split("/");

this.inputDate = this.datepipe.transform(new Date(parsedDate[2] + '-' + parsedDate[1] + '-' + parsedDate[0]), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
this.inputDateFrom = this.datepipe.transform(new Date(parsedDate[5] + '-' + parsedDate[4] + '-' + parsedDate[3]), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
this.inputDateTo = this.datepipe.transform(new Date(parsedDate[8] + '-' + parsedDate[7] + '-' + parsedDate[6]), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Comment: Try to use the 2 way data binding, [(ngModel)]="inputDate"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In  order for binding to work, you need to surround `ngModel` with `[(` like so:

```
<input type="date" [(ngModel)]="inputDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'"">
```

More info on binding can be found [in the docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---)

You also can't use pipes in the `ngModel` binding, so you'll need to remove that:

```
<input type="date" [(ngModel)]="inputDate">
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it's working now but for some reason the day is getting a minus 1, and sometimes the day and month combined. Examples: 01/01/2018 shows 01/31/2018, and 02/03/2018 shows 01/02/2018 (seen this just once)

Comment: In the examples above, what was `data` set to?

Comment: data[4, 5, 6] comes from a table with a 'raw' date passed as a string with the format dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: @prevox I meant what were the values

Comment: And what is the use of the datepipe? Could you not just construct the string yourself and pass it to `inputDate`? I say that because constructing a `Date` object is causing your issue due to timezones.

Comment: Oh, I see the issue now. You're right, there's no need to use datepipe